# Will wordpress login functionality do anything?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I'm building a website and I've decided to use wordpress for the totally public parts (e.g. the blog, about us, etc.), but I still want to have a separate area for registered users of the website that would contain user specific info and options (like chat). My PHP knowledge is limited,  but I can learn how to code login scripts etc. if I need to.

My real question is, can I use the registration and login functionality that is built in to wordpress, or will I need to create my own login DB and scripts so that I can have this user specific content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use build-in login functionality! The required function is [is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in).

Additionally, you can install any of [chat plug-in](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/chat).

Edited: to retrieve user profile data -> [get_profile()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_profile)

Comment: see edited answer. there is get_profile(). Better you check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/ for list of all functions.